# Replace NA in a Dataframe Column with a Value Only when Two Other Columns Are Also NA

Tags: r, tidyverse

library(tidyverse)

Using the sample data below, I'm trying to replace the NA's in Col1 with the number 22222, but only when all three columns are NA. So the final result should only have 22222 in Col1 for rows 4 and 7.

I would like to use tidyverse and I'm attempting something along the lines of:

```
DF%>%mutate_at(vars(Col1),funs(replace(.,if_else(is.na(one_of(Col1,Col2,Col3),22222,.)))))
```

Sample Data:(*not sure if this is the correct way to create real "NA"'s (that work with is.na) in the sample data? My real data has blank cells in the Excel file, which when converted to CSV and imported to R results in NA's*.)

```
Col1<-c(34564,NA,43456,NA,45655,6789,99999,87667)
Col3<-c(45673,88789,11123,NA,55676,76566,NA,NA)
Col1<-c(34564,NA,43456,NA,45655,6789,NA,87667)
Col2<-c(34565,43456,55555,NA,65433,22234,NA,98909)
DF<-data_frame(ID,Col1,Col2,Col3)
```

Comment: There is something weird in your data frame. There are two Col1 and no ID variable in vectors' creation.

Comment: I assumed one `Col1` as ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has a few errors, so my answer will attempt to fill in the blanks. The data frame you have provided does not contain `id`, for example. I have modified your sample to make this reproducible.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(34564, NA, 43456, NA, 45655, 6789, 99999, 87667),
  col1 = c(45673, 88789, 11123, NA, 55676, 76566, NA, NA),
  col2 = c(34564, NA, 43456, NA, 45655, 6789, NA, 87667),
  col3 = c(34565, 43456, 55555, NA, 65433, 22234, NA, 98909)
)
```

To solve a single column, you can just use if/else in a normal mutate.

```
df %>%
  mutate(col1 = if_else(
    is.na(col1) & is.na(col2) & is.na(col3), 22222, col1
  ))

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#      id  col1  col2  col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 34564 45673 34564 34565
# 2    NA 88789    NA 43456
# 3 43456 11123 43456 55555
# 4    NA 22222    NA    NA
# 5 45655 55676 45655 65433
# 6  6789 76566  6789 22234
# 7 99999 22222    NA    NA
# 8 87667    NA 87667 98909
```

Your question suggests you actually want each column mutated, not only `col1`. You can substitute the `funs(replace())` approach you started with to just apply the earlier if/else to each column listed in `vars`.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(col1, col2, col3),
    ~if_else(is.na(df$col1) & is.na(df$col2) & is.na(df$col3), 22222, .)
  )

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#      id  col1  col2  col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 34564 45673 34564 34565
# 2    NA 88789    NA 43456
# 3 43456 11123 43456 55555
# 4    NA 22222 22222 22222
# 5 45655 55676 45655 65433
# 6  6789 76566  6789 22234
# 7 99999 22222 22222 22222
# 8 87667    NA 87667 98909
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer (the first part) is what I was looking for. I only had about 5 min to create the sample data, so I apologize for the error with the ID column, but thanks for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use `mapply` function.

```
#Define a function to replace missing row values
replMissing <- function(x, y, z){
  ifelse(is.na(x) & is.na(y) & is.na(z), 22222, x )
}
# Call mapply and pass value of Col1, Col2 and Col3
DF$Col1 <- mapply(replMissing, DF$Col1, DF$Col2, DF$Col3)

#results
> DF
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     ID  Col1  Col2  Col3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 34564 34564 34565 45673
2    NA    NA 43456 88789
3 43456 43456 55555 11123
4    NA 22222    NA    NA
5 45655 45655 65433 55676
6  6789  6789 22234 76566
7 99999 22222    NA    NA
8 87667 87667 98909    NA
```

The solution will be much simpler using `data.table`.

```
DF <- data.table(DF)
DF[is.na(Col1) & is.na(Col2) & is.na(Col3), Col1 := 22222]
# Result
> DF
      ID  Col1  Col2  Col3
1: 34564 34564 34565 45673
2:    NA    NA 43456 88789
3: 43456 43456 55555 11123
4:    NA 22222    NA    NA
5: 45655 45655 65433 55676
6:  6789  6789 22234 76566
7: 99999 22222    NA    NA
8: 87667 87667 98909    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for any number of column. It will replace the value with `22222` for each rows that is all `NA` value in each column

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
Col1<-c(34564,NA,43456,NA,45655,6789,99999,87667)
Col2<-c(34565,43456,55555,NA,65433,22234,NA,98909)
Col3<-c(45673,88789,11123,NA,55676,76566,NA,NA)
DF<-data_frame(Col1,Col2,Col3)

# Find the rows with all NA. Works with any number of column
all_na <- DF %>%
  is.na() %>%
  apply(1, all)

# Replace the value from this rows with 2222 and keep others
DF %>%
  mutate_all(funs(if_else(all_na, 22222, .)))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>    Col1  Col2  Col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 34564 34565 45673
#> 2    NA 43456 88789
#> 3 43456 55555 11123
#> 4 22222 22222 22222
#> 5 45655 65433 55676
#> 6  6789 22234 76566
#> 7 99999    NA    NA
#> 8 87667 98909    NA
```